# ANTLR4 Context-sensitive rule: unexpected parsing/resynchronization when failing semantic predicate

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm working on a grammar that is context-sensitive. Here is its description:

- It describes the set of expressions.
- Each expression contains one or more parts separated by logical operator.
- Each part consists of optional field identifier followed by some comparison operator (that is also optional) and the list of values.
- Values are separated by logical operator as well.
- By default value is a sequence of characters. Sometimes (depending on context) set of possible characters for each value can be extended. It even can consume comparison operator (that is used for separating of field identifiers from list of values, according to 3rd rule) to treat it as value's character.

Here's the simplified version of a grammar:

```
grammar TestGrammar;

@members {
  boolean isValue = false;  
}

exprSet: (expr NL?)+;

expr: expr log_op expr
    | part
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;

part: (fieldId comp_op)? values;

fieldId: STRNG;

values: values log_op values
      | value
      | '(' values ')'
      ;

value: strng;

strng: (  STRNG 
        | {isValue}? comp_op
       )+;

log_op: '&' '&';

comp_op: '=';       


NL: '\r'? '\n';
WS: ' ' -> channel(HIDDEN);

STRNG: CHR+;
CHR: [A-Za-z];
```

I'm using semantic predicate in **strng** rule. It should extend the set of possible tokens depending on **isValue** variable;

The problem occurs when semantic predicate evaluates to false. I expect that 2 **STRNG** tokens with '=' token between them will be treated as **part** node. Instead of it, it parses each **STRNG** token as a **value**, and throws out '=' token when re-synchronizing.

Here's the input string and the resulting expression tree that is incorrect:

```
a && b=c
```

[image]

To look at correct expression tree it's enough to remove an alternative with semantic predicate from **strng** rule (that makes it static and so is inappropriate for my solution):

```
strng: (  STRNG 
       // | {isValue}? comp_op
       )+;
```

Here's resulting expression tree:

[image]

BTW, when semantic predicate evaluates to true - the result is as expected: **strng** rule matches an extended set of tokens:

```
strng: (  STRNG 
        | {!isValue}? comp_op
       )+;
```

Please explain why this happens in such way, and help to find out correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've realized that current approach is inappropriate for my task.

I've chosen another approach based on overriding of Lexer's nextToken() and emit() methods, as described in [ANTLR4: How to inject tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001009/antlr4-how-to-inject-tokens) .

It has given me almost full control on the stream of tokens. I got following advantages:

- assigning required types to tokens;
- postpone sending tokens with yet undefined type to parser (by sending fake tokens on hidden channel);
- possibility to split and merge tokens;
- possibility to organize postponed tokens into queues.

Having all these possibilities I'm able to resolve all the ambiguities in the parser.

P.S. Thanks to everyone who tried to help, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

What about removing one option from `values`? Otherwise the text `a && b` may be either a

1. `expr` -> `expr` `log_op` `expr`

or

1. `expr` -> `part` ->  `values` `log_op` `values`

.
It seems Antlr resolves it by using the second option!

```
    values
         : //values log_op values
           value
         | '(' values ')'
         ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately it doesn't help. The main reason is: in this way it's impossible to represent list of values, each part will have exactly one value, probably enclosed within parentheses. Anyways, i tried it, with no success... It still represents "b=c" as two parts and throws out '=' token when semantic predicate evaluates to false...

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `expr` rule is written in the wrong order. Try moving the binary expression to be the last alternative instead of the first.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. The result is the same as on first screenshot. It seems that when semantic predicate fails it throws an FailedPredicateException exception that forces error recovery process that goes through call stack down to root (exprSet) node. 2nd expr branch with no leaf. Seems like parser launched fail-safe strategy during recovery (as described in "Error Recovery Fail-Safe" sub-chapter from "The Definitive ANTLR Reference" book). Anyways, still unclear why it can't find correct alternative during recovery.

Comment: I'll have to look into this some more. Specifically regarding recovery: ANTLR 4 does not perform any backtracking under any circumstances. If prediction fails to return the correct alternative on the first try, then it fails to return the correct alternative altogether.