# Is it possible to split a token into 2 in Antlr4?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I need to be able to split one token into 2 for highlighting purposes, I have a token that looks like this:

```
ID_INTERP: '$' IDEN;
```

but I want to highlight the dollar sign differently from the identifier, so is it possible to split this token into two, one with the dollar sign and the other with the identifier? I know I can change the entire token into a different type under certain conditions, but I'd like to be able to add and change what text it contains, basically to change the tokenstream so instead of saying

ID_INTERP["$foo"]

it would see something like this:

DOLLAR_SIGN["$"] IDEN["foo"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by extending your token source to emit more than a single token for a given match. I have used this idea to generate 2 tokens for the lexer rule `DOT_IDENTIFIER` ([see the MySQL grammar in the MySQL Workbench parser](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/8.0/library/parsers/grammars/MySQLLexer.g4#L198)). On match it pushes a dot token and sets the result to `IDENTIFIER`, effectively creating 2 separate tokens for a single rule.

Sam Harwell described the technique to extend your lexer for this approach [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001009/antlr4-how-to-inject-tokens) with some Java code. And here is a possible C++ implementation that I'm using:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<antlr4::Token> MySQLBaseLexer::nextToken() {
  // First respond with pending tokens to the next token request, if there are any.
  if (!_pendingTokens.empty()) {
    auto pending = std::move(_pendingTokens.front());
    _pendingTokens.pop_front();
    return pending;
  }

  // Let the main lexer class run the next token recognition.
  // This might create additional tokens again.
  auto next = Lexer::nextToken();
  if (!_pendingTokens.empty()) {
    auto pending = std::move(_pendingTokens.front());
    _pendingTokens.pop_front();
    _pendingTokens.push_back(std::move(next));
    return pending;
  }
  return next;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is more complete, with a nice reference!

Comment: Thank you! this is what I need.